# Touch events not passing to subviews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, subview

i have a scrollview and inside a uiview that contains multiple subviews ( uiimageview). the problem is i can't pass touch gestures to the imageviews ..

```
@interface photoLibrary (){
    UIView *view_cuImagini;
}
    @property (nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView *scrl_images;
@end

@implementation photoLibrary
@synthesize scrl_images;    
//..
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//...
scrl_images.minimumZoomScale=0.4;
    view_cuImagini=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrl_images.frame.origin.x, scrl_images.frame.origin.y, scrl_images.frame.size.width, scrl_images.frame.size.height)];
    view_cuImagini.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [scrl_images addSubview:view_cuImagini];
}

 -(void)AddImageViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImage:(UIImage*)img andtag:(int)tag{  
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];

         tempimg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

             UIImageView *bifat = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bifat.jpg"]];
         tempimg.image=img;
         tempimg.tag=tag;
         tap.delegate=self;
         tempimg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
         view_cuImagini.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
         [tempimg addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        // [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
         [tempimg addSubview:bifat];
         [view_cuImagini addSubview:tempimg];


 }
 -(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)rec{
     if (rec.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

         NSLog(@"imageTouch with tag %i",rec.view.tag);
}
```

i want to be able to find the which tempimg was touched
does anybody has a solutions for this?

Comment: just want to know one thing.You are adding the gesture to temping(UIImageView).Over that image view you add another image view i.e bit fat.Don't you think something wrong........

Comment: it is a small image in right corner..even without it it won't work... when i had 'tempimg' as subview of uiscrollview it worked..but when i added all the 'temimg' as subview of view which is subview of scrollview it stoped working.... i added that view to be able to zoom out all tempimg

Comment: and so what's your feedback on my solution?

Comment: there you go answer updated.. this should do it (you should make your variables more readable btw.. this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1379499138&sr=8-1&keywords=code+complete) gives you excellent pointers for that